# Помогите с подключением к mysql через Google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

Подготовил запрос из googel sheets:

```
var server = '217.107.34.191';
var port = 3306;
var dbName = 'j8326878';
var username = '047358134_12';
var password = 'Turre566-77-897';
var url = 'jdbc:mysql://'+server+':'+port+'/'+dbName;

function readData() {
 var conn = Jdbc.getConnection(url, username, password);
 var stmt = conn.createStatement();
 var results = stmt.executeQuery('users');
 var metaData=results.getMetaData();
 var numCols = metaData.getColumnCount();
 var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
 var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('mysql');
 sheet.clearContents();
 var arr=[];
```

При запуске выдаёт ошибку в 11 строке: Exception: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'users' at line 1
readData    @ Код.gs:11

Подскажите пожалуйста почему ругается на название таблицы?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var results = stmt.executeQuery('SELECT * FROM `users`');
```

всё оказалось просто.